# Huge empty space under div with image

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, space

I am currently working on a website and at the top of the site I would like to have the logo. However, there appears to be a huge empty space in between the logo and the rest of the site.

HTML:

```
<body><br><br>
<div class="html_logo">
    <div id="slider"><div class="slide"><center><img src="images/Logo fashion nails studio.png"></center></div></div></div>

<header>        <!-- Header Title Start -->
    <center><h1>Welkom op de website van <span>Fashion Nails Studio</span>!</h1></center>
```

CSS:

```
.html_carousel {
}
.html_carousel div.slide {

}   
.html_carousel div.slide img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #c1c1c1;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #c1c1c1;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #c1c1c1;
    border-radius:15px;
}

.clearfix {
    float: none;
    clear: both;
}

.html_logo div.slide img {
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Could you please help me how to fix this?
Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
It seems everyone thinks the empty space under the image is just a few pixels, it is however HUGE HUGE HUGE, like 20 empty lines or so

EDIT EDIT:
It appears to be a javascript problem, since there is no empty space when i temporarily disable javascript on the image, but how do i go about fixing this permanently?

Comment: @IPADDRESS Explain? Baring in mind you can see they are still using `<center>`.

Comment: You should also make sure that you close your image tag properly, it should be <img src="images/Logo fashion nails studio.png" />

Comment: It 's because `h1` tag have some huge space before and after itself by dafult. What you need to do is define a style for `h1` like `h1 {margin-top:0px;}` and of course since this is gonna effect all the `h1` in the site you may wanna do this by class.

Comment: Give the html_logo class a 'top: 0%' value.

Comment: Im not using HTML5 and the suggestions with the margin and top 0% value dindt work im afraid, but thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Also, probably not a good idea to have filenames with spaces.

Comment: the huge empty space seems to go away if i temporarily disable javascript on the picture, but how can i do this permanently

Comment: Please include the relevant JavaScript in your question or remove the JavaScript tag as it is not applicable without the code...

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS>>>>

```
<body><!--<br><br>-->
<div class="html_logo">
<div id="slider"><div class="slide"><center><img src="images/Logo fashion nails studio.png"></center></div></div></div>

<header>        <!-- Header Title Start -->
<center><h1 style="margin:0px;">Welkom op de website van <span>Fashion Nails Studio</span>! </h1></center>
```

Please comment back if this does not work and if you need more help.The H1 element gives extra white space by default

Comment: This didnt work im afraid. but im not talking about a space that is just a few pixels. Im talking about a HUGE space

Comment: it appears to be a problem with the javascript, because if i disable it on the image the empty spacing goes away. Do you know how to fix it, because the disable thing is only temporary

Comment: @Bobray yes I know how to use javascript, if you upload the script I could have a look at it. thanks